# Is Beerus able to use Ultra Instinct?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

When Goku first activated Ultra Instinct Beerus looked pretty worried. Is this because he has yet to unlock Ultra Instinct?

Whis described that is even for gods difficult to attain it. Beerus is a god of destruction. Meaning that it is difficult to attain **even** for gods indirectly indicates that not all gods have Ultra Instinct unlocked *yet*. If this is true, is Beerus one of them then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the manga,

> he is shown to use Ultra Instinct when all the Gods of Destruction were coerced into fighting each other. Everyone ganged up on Beerus because they didn't like him for various reasons, and he was able to successfully fend them all off for a short period of time. It should be noted that he is not at Whis' level, and still training his Ultra Instinct.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]! I fixed the spoiler block for you (you can use `>!` for spoiler block). On the other hand, could you also mention the related manga chapter? Thanks!

Comment: This is really tempting me to read the manga, I can't wait for this to happen in the anime.

Comment: the most recent one, chapter 29

Comment: true, I didnt remember this

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer to this question would be No!

The Ultra Instinct transformation Goku utilizes, is exactly similar to something used by Whis. Where every part of Goku's body moves 100% on its own and eliminates reaction time. Unlike Whis, Goku gains a transformation which also acts a power multiplier while attaining this state. Just like in the cell games, post Hyperbolic time chamber, we see Goku utilizing the SSJ transformation as though he was in his normal state. Goku does not have a similar ability where he can utilise this skill in his normal state without taking up a lot of energy.

All the gods of destruction on the other hand are yet to master this skill are in the process of mastering the same. In other words, Beerus has not mastered it to the same level as Goku or Whis. We see Beerus utilise the same in the manga where he dodges attacks from multiple God's of destructions but at the same time, it is not 100% as he does get caught off guard in the process. This could possibly be another reason why we see him rather annoyed like the other gods when we see Goku utilize this transformation.

Comment: Mastering an ability is different from being able to use it though.

Comment: +Ravi Bechoe When you refer to Ultra Instinct, It would mean the transformation which Goku hasn't mastered. The skill would be self-movement which Goku has mastered and even Beerus hasn't mastered the same.

Comment: According to Whis Ultra Instinct is when the body responds to an action without the brain having to process the action. This simply eleminates a process, which makes it a state and not a transformation. Whis also said that Goku used Ultra Instinct. Being able to use something doesn't mean that you have mastered it. For example I can write english sentences, but I haven't mastered the english language.

Comment: Firstly, Whis has described the technique as self-movement while training Goku and Vegeta. He also states that this technique is incredibly hard to master and even Lord Beerus hasn't mastered it yet. When Beerus utilises the technique, we see that it's not perfect in tha manga. As for Whis, we see him utilizing it in his natural state where he is conscious of what is going on.(Even Beerus was in his natural state). Goku has also mastered the technique like Whis, however, he isn't conscious while utilising the same based on the fact that he didn't know what happened the first time he used it.

Comment: Also, Goku needs a transformation to attain that state. If it was a regular skill, he would be utilizing it in his SSJB form or in all of his transformations. However, he undergoes a unique transformation while utilizing this state which he hasn't mastered yet. So in other words, Goku has mastered self-movement as we have seen an unmastered version of the same being used by Beerus in the manga. What he hasn't mastered is the transformation(Possibly just him or maybe Saiyans in general require), to attain that state.

Comment: Alright I understand the differences from both our point of views, so let's agree to disagree. But back to the main question, your comments basically indicate that Beerus is able to use Ultra Instinct, which answers my question. I didn't ask if he had mastered it. In the anime we didn't know yet that he was even capable of using it, let alone mastering it.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is Ultra Instinct is a transformation and Self-Movement is the technique, Beerus cannot use the transformation. Goku uses a transformation as it clearly acts as a power multiplier or he wouldn't be able to take JIren's attacks in his base form. Goku has mastered the skill of self-movement. The gods all can utilise the skill but not to the same level as Goku while he uses it in his UI transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it isnt exactly the same in the anime and in the manga. In episode 18th of Dragon Ball Super Wiss tells to Goku that exists an ability of moving without thinking that he dominates and that even Beerus hasnt dominated yet

[image]

[image]

[image]